# ember.js, filtering PromiseManyArray in the controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to define a computed property that consists of a filtered `hasMany` relationship. When I loop over the items of the `PromiseManyArray`, I get `undefined` when trying to access the attribute I want to filter on. On later calls to this computed property, everything works fine.

This is a simplified version of my controller code:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    availableModules: function () {
        let thisModule = this.get('model')

        console.log(thisModule.get('library.modules')) // This logs <DS.PromiseManyArray:ember604>

        // loop over siblings
        return thisModule.get('library.modules').filter(mod => {
            // mod.classification is undefined
            return mod.get('classification') !== 'basis'
        })

   }.property('model')
})
```

For the `Module` model we can assume that it has a `classification` attribute, and it belongs to a `Library` object, and the `Library` model `hasMany` modules.

I have tried something like this, and it logs properly the attribute `classification`, but I don't know how to return anything so that the template can render it.

```
availableModules: function () {
    let thisModule = this.get('model')

    thisModule.get('library.modules').then(mods => {
        mods.forEach(mod => {
            console.log(mod.get('classification'))
        })
    })
}.property('model')
```

So the problem seems to be that inside of the `PromiseManyArray.filter` method, the attributes of the found objects are not yet resolved... How can I create a promise that will return all filtered objects once those have been resolved? I don't know how to get my head around this. Thanks.

Comment: Hey so what I would do is instead of fetching the async relationship on the controller, to instead do it in one of the model hooks. So fetch them in the afterModel hook, set it onto the route itself, and then in the setup controller set the async property onto the controller. Then in the controller you can have a computed to filter your async relationship. That way you've got the async relationship loaded into the store and are able to access the loading template while waiting for stuff to load.

Comment: @Bloomfield, that helped, but I don't like it too much. I added an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Bloomfield's comment, and with help of [this thread in the ember forum](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-use-aftermodel-results-in-setupcontroller/6251/16), I have found an acceptable solution. Basically it consists of resolving all the relationships in the route, so that when the controller is called, you don't have to deal with promises.

Solution:

1. In the `model` hook of the route, return a hash of promises of all the needed information
2. Define a custom `setupController`, and inside of it, store the model and the extra data in the controller

The route code looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        let module = this.store.findRecord('module', params.mod_id)

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            module: module,
            siblingModules: module.then(mod => mod.get('library.modules')),  // promise based on previous promise
        })
    },

    setupController(controller, hash) {
        controller.set('model', hash.module)
        controller.set('siblingModules', hash.siblingModules)
    },
})
```

Note: for the route to still work properly, the `{{#link-to 'route' model}}` have to explicitly use an attribute, like the `id`: `{{#link-to 'route' model.id}}`

**Extra info**

Bloomfield's approach consisted of using the `afterModel` hook to load the extra data in an attribute of the `Route` object, and then in the `setupController`, set the extra data in the `Controller`. Something like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('module', params.mod_id)
    },

    afterModel(model) {
        return model.get('library.modules').then(modules => {
            this.set('siblingModules', modules)
        })
    },

    siblingModules: null,  // provisional store

    setupController(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model)
        controller.set('siblingModules', this.get('siblingModules'))
    },
})
```

But this feels like a hack. You have to return a promise in `afterModel`, but you can't access the result. Instead the result has to be accessed via  .then`and then stored in the`Route` object... which is not a nice flow of information. This has however the advantage that you don't have to specify any attribute for the links in the template.

There are more options like using `PromiseProxyArray`, but that's too complicated for a newcomer like me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into PromiseManyArray issues in modern times, make sure you have async: false explicitly set on any hasMany relationships directly serialized by the API.  Modern versions of Ember will behave unexpectedly if you don't, such as computed properties not working when you use pushObject.